# Get all file names from PHP file in Android

Tags: java, php, android

Edit: For all those who are downvoting, this isn't the same question asked many times before.
I'm NOT A PHP developer. I want to retrieve all the images names from a folder on my FTP server. I googled and found this script:

```
<?php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__) as $file) {
  if ($file->isFile()) {
      print $file->getFilename() . "\n";
  }
}
?>
```

Since I'm not a PHP dev, I can't understand even a word of it.

**What I Want:** Modify PHP script so that it returns an array containing file names and want some android code which accepts the array.

Thank You!

Comment: what you want is that you need to start reading and learning things. Simple steps:

1) Go to php.net and start find the functions that do what you need to do
2) Export data to json
3) Make an Http Call from Android with (Retrofit, Apache Http, okHttp, HttpurlConnection whatever suits you best)

Comment: Just fo this small task, I don't want to learn a whole new langauge.

Comment: You don't need to _learn a whole new langauge_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know who wrote that method, but PHP already has a built in method to return the contents of a directory http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

If you only want to include files and not folders with scandir, this answer will help [Include JUST files in scandir array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680121/include-just-files-in-scandir-array)

This answer goes over decoding json with java [Decoding JSON String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java)

Comment: I know how to parse JSON by JSON object name, array name but how to decode? Some links please? It would be easy I think

Comment: Java. Plus, I read your one line code for json_encode using scandir function. But I want files only and not directories.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the details you need. You can easily find this using the search on the site

Comment: Everything fine. How to decode '[".","..","0.txt","1.txt","2.txt"]'?

Comment: I have a link in my answer that shows you how to decode json with java

Comment: I have already checked that but for that, we need a key-value pair. But in this case, I only have the value. Without a key, it's not possible to retrieve value using that link

Comment: Ok, I have generated the JSON properly now. Before I was doing a bit wrong