# php: scan a directory just for files (filename+extension)

Tags: php

I'd like to scan a directory with a php function in order to find out if a file corresponding to a specific filename in database exists or not. When the file doesn't exist as a database entry (is deleted from the DB) the corresponding file should also be deleted from the directory. My problem is: scandir() doesn't only return files. Basically i need the can function in order to use its return value in a foreach.

Comment: Maybe this thread answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680121/include-just-files-in-scandir-array.

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scandir` too, of course. I'd suggest using [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php). with [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Example code:

```
function recursiveDirectoryIterator($path) {
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file) {
    if (!$file->isDir()) {
      yield $file->getFilename(); // You can add $file->getFileExtension() too
    }
  }
}
```

Normally, I'd just leave this as a comment, but I feel most people don't use RecursiveIterator and DirecotryIterator very often, so an example was in order.