# MAC hidden system files

Tags: php, macos, file, loops

While looping through a directory for images using this php code, I need to filter out the system files that my MAC dev computer insists on creating.

First I only had to filter out

```
.DS_Store
```

files, lately there has appeared files looking like this as well:

```
._.DS_Store


    if ($handle = opendir($server_dir)) { //if we could open the directory...
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { //then loop through it...
            if ( ($entry != ".") && ($entry != "..") && (strpos($entry, ".DS_Store") !== false) && (strpos($entry, "._.DS_Store") !== false) ) { //and skip the . and .. entities
                $m .= '
                '.$client_dir.$entry.'
                ';
            }            
        }
        closedir($handle);      
    }
    else {
        echo("Can't open $dir, does it exist? Does www-user have permission to read it?");
    }
```

Is there any other name of hidden system files that I need to filter out or are these two it?

Is there any better way of handling this than the way I do it?

Comment: Also see this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532569/exclude-hidden-files-from-scandir-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
 (strpos($entry, ".DS_Store") !== false) && (strpos($entry, "._.DS_Store") !== false)
```

by this:

```
 !stristr($entry, '.DS_Store')
```

and there is .localized, seen it some places. As @deceze said, unix systems are full of `.` configuration files, it all depends on the directory you're working on.

Or even better you can replace all your if statement by:

```
if(substr($entry, 0, 1)!='.')
```

Answer (score 1):

"[Dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_files#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments)", files starting with a dot, are a long standing convention of UNIX systems for "hidden" files. There are tons of them created by all sorts of programs. Go to the Terminal and play around with `ls -a`. The convention is to be aware of them and ignore them unless you know what you're doing. So, ignore *all* files starting with a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be tons of different hidden files, such as `.svn`, `.git`, as well as your examples above try this ... it checks to see if the first character is a `.`

```
if($entry[0] != '.'){
   // do something as its not a hidden file
}
```