# Does php scandir() exclude hidden files under Windows?

Tags: php, windows, scandir, hidden-files

On a Windows system, a backup agent created temporary hidden files of nearly the same name as the original files, and in the same path. This was probably disturbing a process that used PHP `scandir()`.

Now I was wondering if files on Windows having the hidden flag set are excluded by PHP `scandir()`.

There are some articles about the hidden files in Linux style, how `scandir()` should ignore files that start with a dot, but there is rarely no info about Windows files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short test shows that neither `scandir()` nor `glob()` or others take care of the hidden flag.

Here is the experiment and the result:

[image]

Parts:

- Windows 7
- PHP 5.6.9 (x86)
- Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable x86

So `scandir()` does not hide files having the hidden flag set.

Next question is, can more powerful PHP commands like `glob()` be configured.

Firstly, there is no parameter to deal with flags:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php

Secondly, there is this telling comment of Gabriel S. Luraschi:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php#110510

He recommends `exec('dir ... \A ...')`. But on commercial hostings (if they run on Windows), this will not be allowed.

To be sure: use the Linux style and ignore files that start with a dot, like here:

[Exclude hidden files from scandir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532569/exclude-hidden-files-from-scandir-php)

Comment: Did you try out the answer I have suggested? In windows there is a way to flag out hidden files and prevent them from being printed on screen or to exclude them whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried this code on windows 7 and windows 8 & 8.1 and ***it surely excludes hidden files by flagging them out.***

```
   <?php

    $location="path/to/a/folder/";

    if( function_exists("scandir") ){

        $file = scandir($location);

        foreach($file as $this_file) {
        /***Putting the condition here restricts hidden files and files starting with '.' and '~'...****/
            if (is_hidden_file($location.$this_file) || $this_file == '.' || $this_file == '..' || $this_file[0]=='.' || $this_file[0]=='~' ) 
                continue;

            else {
            var_dump($this_file);
            }

        }       
    }

    function is_hidden_file($fn) {
        $dir = "\"".$fn."\"";
        $attr = trim(shell_exec("FOR %A IN (".$dir.") DO @ECHO %~aA"));
        if($attr[3] === 'h')
            return true;

        return false;
    }
?>
```

I see that you have mentioned in the question that there are ways to exclude files starting with '.' and stuff in linux but very less information about windows. Then check this out it not only eradicates files starting with '.' & '..' but also flags out the actually hidden files and will work for sure in windows.